# Filtering an array by array of objects property

Tags: javascript, filter

The thing that I am doing for now is not giving the correct answer.

As a result, I am getting just the value of brr array:

```
["model/model.yaml", 
 "model/storage-complextypes.yaml", 
 "model/storage-simpletypes.yaml"]
```

Trying to find out where I have made a mistake

```js
let arr = [{
  id: "862d-8f99-4638-ef1d",
  data: "---↵  inventory:↵  - devices:↵      platformtypes:…          extract:↵            path: create_time↵",
  path: "inventory/inventory.yaml"
}, {
  id: "ccad-2ea5-1241-4d1a",
  data: "---↵  model:↵    services:↵    - name: nano↵      …erdelete: cascade↵          apiaccess: readonly↵↵",
  path: "model/model.yaml"
}, {
  id: "5f6d-2ce9-a5e4-dee8",
  data: "---↵  model:↵    packages:↵    - name: storage↵   …olicy rules.↵          type: Collection(string)↵↵",
  path: "model/storage-complextypes.yaml"
}]

const brr = ["model/model.yaml", "model/storage-complextypes.yaml", "model/storage-simpletypes.yaml"]


const res = brr.filter((i) => arr.filter((j) => j.path !== i))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: your inner `filter()` returns an array which is `truthy` and so all elements are included in the outer `filter()`.

Comment: For your inner function you'll probably want either `.every()` or `.some()`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```js
let arr = [{
  id: "862d-8f99-4638-ef1d",
  data: "---↵  inventory:↵  - devices:↵      platformtypes:…          extract:↵            path: create_time↵",
  path: "inventory/inventory.yaml"
}, {
  id: "ccad-2ea5-1241-4d1a",
  data: "---↵  model:↵    services:↵    - name: nano↵      …erdelete: cascade↵          apiaccess: readonly↵↵",
  path: "model/model.yaml"
}, {
  id: "5f6d-2ce9-a5e4-dee8",
  data: "---↵  model:↵    packages:↵    - name: storage↵   …olicy rules.↵          type: Collection(string)↵↵",
  path: "model/storage-complextypes.yaml"
}]

const brr = ["model/model.yaml", "model/storage-complextypes.yaml", "model/storage-simpletypes.yaml"]

const paths = arr.map(({path}) => path)
const res = brr.filter(path => paths.includes(path))

console.log(res)
```

Other way around:

```js
let arr = [{
  id: "862d-8f99-4638-ef1d",
  data: "---↵  inventory:↵  - devices:↵      platformtypes:…          extract:↵            path: create_time↵",
  path: "inventory/inventory.yaml"
}, {
  id: "ccad-2ea5-1241-4d1a",
  data: "---↵  model:↵    services:↵    - name: nano↵      …erdelete: cascade↵          apiaccess: readonly↵↵",
  path: "model/model.yaml"
}, {
  id: "5f6d-2ce9-a5e4-dee8",
  data: "---↵  model:↵    packages:↵    - name: storage↵   …olicy rules.↵          type: Collection(string)↵↵",
  path: "model/storage-complextypes.yaml"
}]

const brr = ["model/model.yaml", "model/storage-complextypes.yaml", "model/storage-simpletypes.yaml"]


const res = arr.filter(({path}) => brr.includes(path))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Sir, I need to filter `brr` array by the "path" property of `arr` array

Comment: @mplungjan A minor thing. You don't need `Object.values(arr)` (used to get the `paths` array) since `arr` is an array. `const paths = arr.map(({ path }) => path)`.